# How do I perform a random event in Python by picking a random variable?

Tags: python, random

Let's say I have to variables, dog and cat. Dog = 5, and cat = 3. How would I tell Python to pick one of these variables by random and print it to the screen?

Comment: @SilentGhost: thanks for pointing that out, now I'm aware that I will likely not get the rep I should for my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import random
print random.choice([dog, cat])
```

It's that simple. `choice()` takes a sequence and returns a random selection from it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that dog and cat can be anything: functions, string keys into a dictionary, numbers...so if you want to perform a random event, you can have them be functions and `random.choice([dog, cat])()`.

Comment: @Nathon: good point. The argument passed to `choice()` can be anything iterable, and in Python it's very easy to make a list composed of literally anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the variables you want to choose from in a list and use the random module to pick one for you.

```
import random
dog = 5
cat = 3
vars = [dog,cat]
print random.sample(vars, 1)
```

The sample method takes two arguments: the population you want to choose from, and the number of samples you want (in this case you only want one variable chosen).

Answer (score 0):

*I tried out the first method and second method, and none of them worked.
So I am using a version of python which is 3.0, and this is the only
thing that actually worked. The solutions are deprecated.*
Not true, wrong post.

Here is the working solution:

```
import random
dog = str([5])
cat = str([3])
variables = dog, cat
print(random.sample(variables, 1))
```

Comment: Whoops. Sorry! Wrong code, how do I edit the post?

Comment: So I was on the wrong question, but I just made the code unnecessarily longer but a bit easier to read.

import random
dog = str([5])
cat = str([3])
variables = dog, cat
print(random.sample(variables, 1))

Comment: it would look like
import random
dog = str([5])
cat = str([3])
variables = dog, cat
print(random.sample(variables, 1))