# Syntax to call random function from a list

Tags: python

From this thread:
[How do I perform a random event in Python by picking a random variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998908/how-do-i-perform-a-random-event-in-python-by-picking-a-random-variable)

I learned that it's possible to put some functions into a list, and by using `random.choice()`, call one of them to generate a random event.

I'm interested in doing this because I'm writing a fairly small text based game as part of a beginner's tutorial.

But when I write what I think will give me the desired result(that is, just one of the functions being called and printing its string:

```
import random

def func_test_1():
    print "This is func_test_1."

def func_test_2():
    print "This is func_test_2."

def func_test_3():
    print "This is func_test_3."

my_list = [func_test_1(), func_test_2(), func_test_3()]

random.choice(my_list)
```

I get this result:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c python random_func.py

This is func_test_1.

This is func_test_2.

This is func_test_3.

Hit any key to close this window...
```

Which is all three functions being called and printing.

Could someone help me out with the correct syntax to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With the parentheses you call the function. What you want is assigning them to the list and call the choice later:

```
my_list = [func_test_1, func_test_2, func_test_3]
random.choice(my_list)()
```

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, when you do `my_list = [func_test_1(), func_test_2(), func_test_3()]` you store function results, not functions in the list. Do `my_list = [func_test_1, func_test_2, func_test_3]` instead and then call random function. Like this:

```
my_list = [func_test_1, func_test_2, func_test_3]
random.choice(my_list)()
```

Comment: Thank you ikostia. I appreciate your time and your response.

Answer (score 11):

*Functions are objects in Python.*

If you refer to them just by their name (without the parentheses, which do actually *call* the function!), you refer to the underlying function objects. You can re-bind them, inspect them .. or store a reference to them in a list.

`mylist = [test_func_1,test_func_2,..]`

At this point, none of the functions has been executed. You can then use `random.choice` to pick a function from the list and invoke it using `()`:

- `mylist[0]()` calls the first function in the list
- `random.choice(mylist)()` calls a random function