# I would like to total the amount of correct answers and display it at the end getting error local variable referenced

Tags: python, python-3.x

just wondering why the error says NameError name question1 is not defined

count = 0
import random

my_list = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8,question9, question10, question11, question12, question13, question14, question15, question16, question17, question18, question19, question20, question21, question22, question23, question24, question25, question26, question27, question28, question29, question30, question31, question32, question33, question34, question35, question36, question37, question38, question39, question40]

def intro(start):
    if start == "YES" or start == "Y":
        print("Lets begin.")
    else:
        print("Thanks for checking it out! Bye Bye!")

def question1():
    global count

```
text_file = open("q1.txt")
print (text_file.read())
text_file.close

item = ""
ans1 = "B"
while item != "A" and item != "B" and item != "C" and item != "D":
    item = input()
if item == (ans1):
    print ("Correct")
    count += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect")
return count
```

def main():
    print("Hello There! Welcome to an all new Trivial Pursuit!")
    print("You have twenty multiple choice questions and twenty true and      false.")
    print ("Each question is one point. Your score will be presented at the end. ")
    print("Would you like to begin? Press Y or YES. Please answer all questions in CAPS.")

```
start = input()
intro(start)

random.choice(my_list)()

question1()
question2()
question3()
question4()
question5()
question6()
question7()
question8()
question9()
question10()
question11()
question12()
question13()
question14()
question15()
question16()
question17()
question18()
question19()
question20()
question21()
question22()
question23()
question24()
question25()
question26()
question27()
question28()
question29()
question30()
question31()
question32()
question33()
question34()
question35()
question36()
question37()
question38()
question39()
question40()




print("You got", count, "right out of 40!")
```

main()

Comment: Do you have a question? _I would like to ..._ should probably be put into question body.

Comment: hello i would like to add up the correct answers and display them at the end of the quiz

Comment: it says File "C:/Users/VvBURNvV/Desktop/Programming_MidTerm/fun.py", line 25, in question1
    count = count + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `count` global:

```
count = 0

def intro(start):
    if start == "yes" or start == "y":
        print("Lets begin.")
    else:
        print("Thanks for checking it out! Bye Bye!")


def question1():

    global count
    count += 1
    return count


def question2():

    global count
    count += 1
    return count


def main():

    print("Hello There! Welcome to an all new Trivial Pursuit!")
    print("You have twenty multiple choice questions and twenty true and false.")
    print ("Each question is one point. Your score will be presented at the end. ")
    print("Would you like to begin? Press y or yes")

    start = input()
    intro(start)

    question1()
    question2()

    print("You got", count, "right!")

main()
```

I edited your code to have the functions just add to `count`. I know globals aren't recommended, but this may work for you.

Comment: is there any way to random the function order by chance like if i wanted the order of my questions/functions to appear in a different order

Comment: Yes. See this answer here, it's explained well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465455/syntax-to-call-random-function-from-a-list

Comment: awesome, do i put the my_list = [func_test_1, func_test_2, func_test_3]
random.choice(my_list)() in the main or at the beginning of my code

Comment: i see this       my_list = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8,
NameError: name 'question1' is not defined  i have the list at the top of my document and i have the    random.choice(my_list)()   in my main

Comment: Put both in your main. You're going to have to adapt your functions to do what you want though.

Comment: i got it working now thank you so much please disregard my edits above you were so helpful

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as the solution if it was what worked for you. Thank you :)