# How to randomly choose method from a list of methods with different arguments?

Tags: python, random

I have object `a` of `class b` with methods `foo(), boo(), noo(arg)`. Now I want to randomly choose one of them without extending the `class b`. The problem is that if I use technics supposed here: [Syntax to call random function from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465455/syntax-to-call-random-function-from-a-list) , then I have to have the same arguments of my methods. 
So I can't use smth like this:

```
my_list = [a.foo, a.boo, a.noo]    
random.choice(my_list)()
```

I case of `noo` method I need to call it with `arg`: `a.noo(arg)`. So how to do it in pythonic way?

Comment: Why don't you use an `if` do the a.noo case ?

Comment: but is this pythonic way?

Comment: If the solution works for you, it doesn't need to be 'pythonic'

Comment: I mean, it might be shorter. Can't I specify somehow the arg for noo function in a list?

Comment: You need to call a random function, but each call should be made with a particular set of arguments, is that it?

Comment: can you add the class and the methods?

Comment: Yes, but noo should always be called with the same value of arg

Comment: are the amount of arguments the same for all the functions?

Comment: No, foo() and boo() have no arguments, and noo(arg) should always have the same constant arg when called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random

funcs = [foo, boo, noo]
args = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [2]]
choice = random.randint(len(funcs))

funcs[choice](*args[choice])
```

This way you have the flexibility to call any function with dynamic arguments, depending on your methods.

Remember to keep the arguments and the functions in the same order

**Edit:** You can also do as suggested in the comments (which i think it's easier, thank you!):

```
import random

calls = [(foo, [1,2,3]), (boo, [4,5]), (noo, [2])]
choice = random.choice(calls)

choice[0](*choice[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. Although if you want to have functions with more than 1 argument it's probably best to send it as a list and unpack it at the function.

```
import random

def foo():
    print('foo')

def boo():
    print('boo')

def noo(arg):
    print('noo:', arg)

my_list = [(foo,), (boo,), (noo, 'hello world')]
for i in range(10):
    choice = random.choice(my_list)
    if len(choice) == 1:
        choice[0]()
    else:
        choice[0](choice[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this was suggested in comment:

```
import random

my_list = [a.foo, a.boo, a.noo]  
rand = random.choice(my_list)
if rand.__name__ == 'noo':
    rand(arg)
else:
    rand()
```